# cdk-Table works but mat-Table does not work

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to put a table on my page and I tried using of mat-Table.

I did everything that is necessary step by step like this page https://material.angular.io/components/table/example.

Unfortunately, When I go to the page it will redirect to the home page and didn't show anything, but if I change the mat-table to CDK-table it will show the table.

Why is this problem happening? Does anyone have an idea?

Here is the code:

Html:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
   </ng-container>

   <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
   <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
 </table>
```

TS file :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

Comment: please add some code here

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Dear Hsuan Lee, There isn't any error in the output console.

Comment: did you add MatTableModule to your module?

Comment: Dear Ehsan, Yes, I add both MatTableModule and CDKTableModule to my module.